# How to get program files environment setting from VBScript

Tags: vbscript, environment-variables

In a batch file you can use %PROGRAMFILES% to get the location of the program files directory,  how do you do it in a VBScript?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Echo wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%PROGRAMFILES%")
```

Comment: Nice, thanks.  I have been resorting to reading the registry, but your answer is far better.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

To get Program Files (x86) use:

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Echo wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%")
```