# Determining the location of Program Files using VBS

Tags: vba, vbscript, directory, special-folders

What would a safe way of extracting the 'Program Files' directory location using VBS?. I would like to get the directory location from the environment as it will avoid localization issues as well as problems between different OS architectures (32/64 bit) and drive (C:\, D:\, etc:).

So far I came across an example given on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx) yet I can get the script to work in VBS, every run just complains about different errors. Here is what they've got on an example script for .net to get the *Sys32* folder.

```
' Sample for the Environment.GetFolderPath method
Imports System

Class Sample
   Public Shared Sub Main()
      Console.WriteLine()
      Console.WriteLine("GetFolderPath: {0}", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System))
   End Sub 'Main
End Class 'Sample
'
'This example produces the following results:
'
'GetFolderPath: C:\WINNT\System32
'
```

---

As Helen mentioned, this is my script to determine the OS Architecture and depending on the outcome I wish to retrieve the respective 'Program Files' path

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & sPC  & "\root\cimv2")
Set colOperatingSystems = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
For Each objOperatingSystem in colOperatingSystems
    sSystemArchitecture = objOperatingSystem.OSArchitecture
Next
```

Comment: how are you running this? It looks more like VB.NET than VBS or VBA.

Comment: On 64-bit Windows, there're `Program Files` and `Program Files (x86)`. Which one do you need?

Comment: .. good point Helen. My code below returns x86

Comment: @oracle; true that. Sorry I mistakenly identified it as vbs. I meant something like that in vbs.

@Helen; you are completely right, I am first checking whether the OS Architecture is 32 or 64 and depending I want to locate the respective folder. See update above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for vbs  from [How to get program files environment setting from VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891261)

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Echo wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%PROGRAMFILES%")
```

if you are in vba

```
Sub GetMe()
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
MsgBox wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%PROGRAMFILES%")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thats excellent, thanks! The code above will return the 64bit 'Program Files' folder. The return 32 bit 'Program Files' folder under a x64 environment  use `%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%`

Comment: In VBA you could use `Environ("PROGRAMFILES")`