# How to open any exe if path is unknown using vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

I can open EXE using following way. But sometimes, path is not fixed. If user change the installation path, following code will be useless.

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Exec("C:\Program Files (x86)\MyAppFolder\MyApp.exe") 
Set objShell = Nothing
```

I have referred following links as suggested

1- [Launch programs whose path contains spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340355/launch-programs-whose-path-contains-spaces) : But this suggest using path or using Run. In my case path is not fixed. User is free to install application anywhere. I have tried using Run as given in that link but my application doesn't open from Run as example suggests

2- [How to get program files environment setting from VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891261/how-to-get-program-files-environment-setting-from-vbscript/1891302#1891302) : This link also contains some solution to get Program File path. But as I said above user is free to install anywhere.

Please suggest how to open EXE if path is not predecided.

Comment: This question is unanswerable as stated. If you don't know the path of the EXE what do you know?

Comment: @MargaretBloom If the system is 32 Bit, there is no Program Files (x86) folder, else there will be. How to manage in this situation?? There must be some way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Launch programs whose path contains spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340355/launch-programs-whose-path-contains-spaces)

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1891302/603855

Comment: @Pirate my question is different because I am not able to open exe from Run.

Comment: @NanjiMange - you have **two** problems: how to determine the programs folder **and** how to quote a path with spaces. So combine both solutions

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner Here the problem is user can change installation folder. How can I open it if user change the folder and set to another drive. Please suggest

Comment: Search for the file, obviously.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Yes, I think this looks a way at the moment.